# string escape double quotes inside single quotes

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm trying to get `' "searchparameter*" '` for full-text containstable SQL statement .

```
string.Format("INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(dba.{0}, *, ' \"{1}*\" ') as KEY_TBL on {2}.{3} = KEY_TBL.[KEY]", tableName, searchParameter, alias, columnName);
```

OUTPUT:

```
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(dba.table, *, ' \"searchparameter*\" ') as KEY_TBL on table.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

PREFERED OUTPUT:

```
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(dba.table, *, ' "searchparameter*" ') as KEY_TBL on table.id = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

The double quote is right, how do I get rid of the backslash?

Comment: Are you _certain_ about the output? Or is that what Visual Studio shows you on hovering over the variable?

Comment: I just ran the same code in a Console application and got your desired output.  Also, your output looks wrong.  You have a \ after your second `"` at the end of `searchparameter`.

Comment: Visual Studio Shows the output hovering over the variable

Comment: Visual Studio shows string values as C# string literals - enclosed in `"` and with `"` escaped to `\"`. So the `\` isn't really there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the string in that format because the value inside the Watch screen is enclosed in double quotes. Hence any inner quotes must be escaped for the string to still be valid and displayable.
If you dig deep and look at the real value (e.g. using the text Visualizer) you will see that it is exactly the one you want.

[image]